# How can I download a stanza's model via command line?

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-stanza

One can download a stanza's model via Python [as follows](https://pypi.org/project/stanza/) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200708034746/https://pypi.org/project/stanza/)):

```
import stanza
stanza.download('en')       # This downloads the English models for the neural pipeline
```

How can I download a stanza's model via command line?

E.g. with spaCy one can use:

```
python -m spacy download en
```

I unsuccessfully tried:

```
python -m stanza download en
```

I use `stanza==1.0.1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using to `-m` argument for the Python interpreter, you can use `-c` (command). To replicate your download call would look like this:

```
python -c 'import stanza; stanza.download("en")'
```